# stop/pause video when modal closes/hides

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, youtube-api, bootstrap-modal

I know this has been asked and answered, but I'm not having any luck with any of the options that I've found. I'm trying to have the video stop playback or pause the video when the modal closes. One problem I'm having is the ability to target the close button. I've put console.logs in the functions I've tried and they weren't registering in the console at all. Thanks for any insights able to be offered.

```
<div id="myModal<%= index + 1 %>"  data-id='<%= list.video_id %>'class="modal fade videoModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content bmd-modalContent" >
            <div class="modal-body modal-header">
              <div class="close-button">
                <button id='single' type="button" class="close fancybox-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label='Close' ><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              </div>
              <div class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9'>
                <iframe id='player' class='embed-responsive-item' src="https://youtube.com/embed/<%= list.video_id %>?rel=0&enablejsapi=1" allowFullScreen='true' frameborder="0"></iframe>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

***EDIT:***
Sorry, I'had tried so much jQuery that I didn't have any in my app.js folder at the time. Here is what I'm working with now.

```
$('[id^=myModal]').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(event) {
  console.log(player);
  event.target.stopVideo();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update the question with more details**

Its really hard to tell what is the problem because you only posted html. You having problem with locating close button and your console.log doesnt trigger. Obviously your javascripe file has some errors above your console.log line.

To detect if modal is closed you can use this EVENT

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

I would not change id of modals when generating them, instead I would put `data-attr` on this element to have one `.on('hidden.bs.modal')` and to have control over every modal

**UPDATE:**

from youtube-api docs https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player

It has been said that if you embed in your html `iframe` with the youtube video then in the moment u make something like this in js:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById("my-video");
    video = new YT.Player(iframe);
}
```

you dont have to define attributes of Player that you create, it will take it from the iframe.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ux86c7t3/2/

Comment: When I don't have a specific, dynamic data-target it plays the first video in the list even if I click on another one.

Comment: what list what video. I dont understand where is the actual problem. what i meant as data-attr, it could be data-id just to know which modal you close. Imagine that u need to handle EVENT for every modal, and every modal has different id, so you will duplicate this `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})` ? Rather not. rather you would have one event that fires whenever any modal closes and inside of that u localize by this (e) in function which one... still not much detail in question

Comment: I'm iterating over a collection of video objects(list == video, my naming of things is terrible :P). I didn't put the iteration start there bc I didn't think it was relevant. I didn't have an js in my original quesiton bc I didn't have any at the time of asking as I had tried so many different things that I ended up deleting the function and hoped to find a solution here.  I've tried targetting the class of the parent element. I'm just not as fluent in JS to really articulate my script problem

Comment: you should repair name convention because its misleading ;] list should be list, video should be called video :) I can see that rails generate this `modal.html`. Propably you can open it, play video, close it and video stops.  I dont know if at the time its only one modal that u generate or you choose between few videos and you want to swap content of your modal, or you dont want to swap content but you generated few modals and every one has its own content with video, so your modal could have`.className` and then u could use event this way `$('.className').on...to have control over all modals

Comment: i mean this event $('.className').on('hidden.bs.modal') and inside this event you would need to localize id of video that you want to stop, propably based on what is inside that modal... There are lot of possibilites and I dont know which one you want to accomplish

Comment: Ya, I'm just trying to get the video to stop playing when the modal closes or hides.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'm still having problems implementing it. But you have for sure given me a path forward :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can simply remove the src of the iframe and then put back again like; so the iframe stops running.

```
 <iframe id="videosContainers" class="yvideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kjsdaf  ?>" w></iframe>
 <span onclick="stopVideo(this.getAttribute('vdoId'))" vdoId ="yvideo" id="CloseModalButton"  data-dismiss="modal"></span>
```

now the Jquery part

```
function stopVideo(id){
  var src = $j('iframe.'+id).attr('src');
  $j('iframe.'+id).attr('src','');
  $j('iframe.'+id).attr('src',src);

}
```